# Find two generators of $K[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find two different generating systems of $K[x,y,z]$ as a $K$-algebra and then make them into one.

I know that for such a generating system it would mean that all elements of $K[x,y,z]$ could be written as linear combinations of the elements in the generating systems but I have absolutely no idea what exactly to do. I also don't know what difference it makes for the generators if we see it as a K-algebra and not the polynomial ring. Been reading all day about it and there are no concrete examples whatsoever which might help me a bit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A $k$-algebra $A$ is said to be generated by a finite set $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\subseteq A$ if the $k$-algebras homomorphism $k[X_1,\dots X_n]\to A$ defined by $X_i\mapsto a_i$ is surjective. If, as in your case, $A=k[X_1,\dots , X_n]$, clearly $\{X_1,\dots X_n\}$ is a set of generators, since the identity on $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is surjective. It's easy to see that (if $\operatorname{char} k\neq 2$) another set of generators could be $\{2X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n\}$.

Saying that $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ generates $A$ as a ring means that the ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z[X_1,\dots,X_n]\to A$ defined by $X_i\mapsto a_i$ is surjective. So if $A=k[X_1,\dots , X_n]$, when $\operatorname{char} k=0$, notice that  $\{X_1,\dots X_n\}$ defines the inclusion $\mathbb Z[X_1,\dots,X_n]\hookrightarrow k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, that isn't surjective. Plus $\{2X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n\}$ and $\{X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n\}$ don't even generate the same subring in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, while they generated the same $k$-algebra.

Comment: Are you assuming that $k$ has characteristic $0$?

Comment: For your first paragraph, yes.  But if $\mathrm{char} \: k = p$, then the map $\mathbb Z[X_1, \dots, X_n] \to k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ is no longer an inclusion, and it is in fact surjective if $k = \mathbb F_p$.  Also, $\{2X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ and $\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ do generate the same subring in odd characteristic.